# 3 Column Div - Left and Right fluid width and the Middle is have a fixed width

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

So, i have this dilemma with a three column div.

what i'm trying to achieve is the Center Div should be responsive and aligned center with a max width of 1000px. this can easily achieve using these css codes:

```
#center{max-width:1000px; width:100%; margin:0px auto; }
```

[image]

and then the left and right div should cover the remaining space. it's like the width of the Left and right = Total width MINUS the width of the center div.

http://jsfiddle.net/bendaggers/zb38d/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"><a href="/">Image Logo JPG here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    background-color:black;
}
.center {
    display:table-cell;
}
.center a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%; max-width:1000px;
}
```

the problem is its not working. here's the fiddle.

can some one help?

Comment: looks like you have assigned `50%` for left and right. How your middle will stretch?

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to have the center responsive and you would like to have 3 equal width columns then you should set the width to 33.3%. One trick you could set the width of your central column as 34% and the left and right as 33% width.

If you want to avoid to take into account of border and padding applied to those 3 columns you could also apply box-sizing:border-box;

```
 /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
    *, *:before, *:after {
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

This way border and padding will not expand the width of the column but instead will be applied inside each column width.

Also you can then center the a link inside the center column.

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    width:33%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:33%;
    background-color:black;
}
.center {
    display:table-cell;
    width:34%; max-width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/zb38d/7/

**Otherwise** if you want the center to be fixed width then simply set a width in pixels or em:

`.center{ width: 1000px; }` but then you will need to set a different percentage of your left and right column then, different from 33%. Otherwise you will support only very high resolutions this way because you are setting a fixed width of 1000px for the center column.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your help. unfortunately, i really need the center div to have a max-width of 1000px and to be centered in the screen. and the left and right should cover the remaining space..

Comment: Hi Kareen, so what kind of design you are after? You want the site to be responsive and have what kind of ratios in percentages between left, center and right? 33% 34% 33% ? Or you want let's say 60% center and then 20% 20% the left and right?

Comment: Center: Max-width 1000px; Left & Right: Body Width Minus the width of Center div. That's what im after for.

Comment: Yes I understand what you want to achieve but in CSS you need to set the percentage of each column unless you want to do that in Javascript and calculate the size of left and right column basing it on the size of the center which will have to expand to max 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to re-think how you're designing this. The first answer with percentages is the best. White space is key to good design; filling up a page is not necessary.

Anyway, this uses jQuery to calculate the left and right, plus it uses the display-table, which doesn't allow for max-width, just width. Using just floats had a hard time with sub-pixels, so the display table worked better. It only makes sense to use this type of layout at 1450px and greater, then rely on different css for the other sizes below that. Because of the jQuery, it calculates the width and sticks the style into the parsed html, so !important is required for css below the 1450 min-width.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/miqetu/1**

Only tested on Firefox on a desktop. I have know idea if this works on touch devices or other browsers without issue.

```
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.col {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: none!important;
    clear: both!important;
}

.inner {
    padding: 20px
}

.column-1 {
    background: #ccc
}

.column-2 {
    background: #ddd
}

.column-3 {
    background: #eee
}

@media (max-width:1449px) { 
    /* used to over-ride jQuery*/

    .wrapper {
        display: block!important
    }

    .col {
        display: block!important
    }

    .column-1,
    .column-2,
    .column-3 {
        clear: both;
        float: none!important;
        width: 100%!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1450px) { 
    .inner {
        padding: 30px
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .col {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .column-2 {
        width: 800px /*max-width won't work */
    }
}


@media (min-width:1500px) { 

    .column-2 {
        width: 1000px /*max-width won't work */
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col column-1"><div class="inner">...</div></div>
  <div class="col column-2"><div class="inner">....</div></div>
  <div class="col column-3"><div class="inner">...</div></div>
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(window).on("load resize", function() {
    if ($('body').width() >= 1450) {

    var ww = $(window).width();
    var rem = ww - $('.column-2').width();
    $('.column-1, .column-3').css('width', rem / 2);
    }
});
```